# Maven isn't pulling my dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have

mvn dependency:resolve

```
[INFO] [dependency:resolve {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO]    org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.2:compile
```

In the pom.xml

```
 39   <dependency>                                                                  
 40         <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>                                            
 41         <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>                                          
 42         <version>1.8.2</version>                                                
 43   </dependency>                                                                 
 44   </dependencies>
```

But when running the code

```
java -jar /home/andref/AndroidStudioProjects/PostCrossJsoup/postcrossing-jsoup/target/postcrossing-jsoup-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get

```
Hello World!
class com.far.postcrossing.jsoup.Connect Connect fetch https://www.postcrossing.com method GET
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
        at com.far.postcrossing.jsoup.Connect.fetch(Connect.java:57)
        at com.far.postcrossing.jsoup.Connect.getCSRF(Connect.java:37)
        at com.far.postcrossing.jsoup.Auth.goAuth(Auth.java:45)
        at com.far.postcrossing.jsoup.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 4 more
```

this exception it's not finding the depency

```
    <configuration>
        <archive>
                <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.far.postcrossing.jsoup.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
   </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: Do a `mvn clean package`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From configuration your Project has a compile dependency to `jsoup`.

Your Project fails during execution of the application.
If you really need `jsoup` during compilation, the compilation phase would have failed if maven did not download/resolve the `jsoup` dependency.

It's more likely that you have not configured the assembly plugin correctly or even you use the wrong jar(the one without dependencies).

According to the [Maven Assembly Plugin Page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) the default name of a jar with dependencies is `<projectname>-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

From the [Maven Assembly Plugin Page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html):

> Then, to create a project assembly, simple execute the normal package phase from the default lifecycle:
>   you need to attach it with a phase explicitly [Execution: Building an Assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)
>
> `mvn package` When this build completes, you should see a file in the
>   target directory with a name similar to the following:
>
> `target/sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

in your case the expected jar is something like:
`target/postcrossing-jsoup-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: I was missing the plugin maven-assembly-plugin